# How to work with Base 8 (Octal) numbers?

Tags: c++, octal

In C++, an octal number is defined by preceeding it with a `0`, example:

```
01 = 1
010 = 8
014 = 12
```

So I was experimenting how working with Base 8 in c++ works, and tried adding to it with a loop, like so:

```
int base8Number = 00;
for (int i = 01; i < 011; i+=01)
{
    base8Number += i;
    cout << base8Number << '\n';
}
```

And apparently, C++ doesn't like working with octal numbers, the output I got is as follows:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
```

The most obvious reason I know it's not working in Base 8, is the `28` output as a result, since the `8` number isn't used in Base 8.

So, my question: Can you work with Base 8 in c++, or is it just meant to be used as a constant, and if you can work with Base 8 in c++, how do you do it?

Comment: It's working in base 2, like all numbers in a standard computer.  You are then asking for the binary value to be displayed in base 10 by using `<<`.  (The `0` + number notation is only for *literals* -- just like `0x` for hex -- and does not magically modify the way the binary value is stored and manipulated.)

Comment: `cout` displays in decimal by default. It has no way of knowing you want octal - it has no idea that you used octal constants in your code. You have to tell it you want it to display octal.

Comment: (But note that when you, say, add 2 16-bit numbers, you are adding 5.33 octal digits together, since each digit is 3 bits.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first, let's remember that when we print numbers the way you're doing, they will be shown in decimal.

Now, let's rewrite your code without octal:

```
int base10Number = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i+=1)
{
    base10Number += i;
    cout << base10Number << '\n';
}
```

So let's now look at what your code is actually doing:

```
cout << 1             << "\n"; // 1
cout << 1 + 2         << "\n"; // 3
cout << 1 + 2 + 3     << "\n"; // 6
cout << 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 << "\n"; // 10
....
```

Which is what you're seeing. So **no**, there is no problem with how octal works in c++.

If you'd like you can use [`std::oct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) to tell [`std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) to use octal printing. For example:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::oct << 25 << "\n"; // Outputs: 31
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that "base" is a property of number representation, not the number itself.  If you've got enough pegs to put one on each finger,  then that is the same number of pegs regardless of whether you write `10`, `012` `0xA`, or anything else.

Your code computes the numbers which would be shown in base 10 as `1`, `3`, `6`, `10`, `15`, etc.  You  output them in base 10.  To output them in base 8 use:

```
std::cout << std::oct << base8Number << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things going on here.

Intrinsically, your computer operates in binary (base 2). When you do something like `int foo = 10;`, you are expressing the number `10` in decimal form because it's convenient for you to read it that way, but in the end the computer will still store it using binary, e.g. `1010`.

If you were to use an octal literal (e.g. `012`), then as far as the computer's concerned that's still just a `1010` binary constant - the only thing that's changed is its representation in the source code.

Finally, the last thing to realise is that the computer will by default output integers in base 10, because that's what's easy for people to read. It's still outputting the number `1010`, just using the decimal representation of it.

Given all of the above, your code is entirely equivalent to doing the following, which you can verify for yourself produces the same output without using any octal:

```
int num = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 9; i += 1) // Constants the same, just changed from octal representation to decimal.
{
    num += i;
    cout << num << '\n'; // Outputs in decimal, as with original program.
}
```

To get what you expect, try using the [`oct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) modifier:

```
int base8Number = 00;
for (int i = 01; i < 011; i+=01)
{
    base8Number += i;
    cout << oct << base8Number << '\n';
    //       ^--Here. Explicitly requests octal output.
}
```

This then explicitly requests that the computer output the values using octal.