# Is there a way i could end a loop with a char in c++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am new to programming, and I am currently trying to figure my way around C++. I am working on a program that will display basic information about employees to the users, and I want the program to end when the users entered a char. However, while working through it, I encountered a problem. When I enter the char (x), it somehow looped from 1-120 (as you seen in the counter below), but when I entered its ASCII number (120), it ended the program as intended. Can anyone explain it to me and what are the possible solutions?

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Employee
{
public:
    int Age;
    string Name;
    int ID;

    void information()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << Name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << Age << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << setfill('0') << setw(3) << ID << endl;
    }

    Employee(string name, int age, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        ID = id;
    }
};

void createProfile()
{
    int age;
    int id;
    string name;
    cout << "Enter the Employee Name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter the Employee Age: ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Enter the Employee ID: ";
    cin >> id;
}
int main()
{
    int num, counter;
    const char stop = 'x';

    cout << "Choose an Employee " << endl;
    cout << "001 Jack" << endl;
    cout << "002 Susan" << endl;
    cout << "003 to create profile" << endl;
    cout << "Press x to Exit";
    for (num = 0; num != stop; num++)
    {
        cout << "\n\nEnter the Employee ID: ";
        cin >> num;
        counter += 1;
        if (num == 001)
        {
            Employee jack = Employee("Jack", 25, 001);
            jack.information();
        }
        else if (num == 002)
        {
            Employee jack = Employee("Susan", 23, 002);
            jack.information();
        }
        else if (num == 003)
        {
            createProfile();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Input invalid";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n" << counter;
}
```

Comment: Your "menu" says `-1` to exit, and you're reading the menu selection in an integer. Where did your sudden expectation that `x` should be a valid selection?

Comment: declare num as char type

Comment: Offtopic: It will be interesting when you will use magic number in this form: `008`

Comment: Check https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html - 120 happens to be the ASCII code of the character `x` !

Comment: Also what's with that `for`? Why are you incrementing `num`? Why are you not exiting when you get the exit condition? Why are you not displaying the `003` option's result? Why are you not building an employee in `003`? This is F material right here.

Comment: You should read about octal numbers since you have leading 0s. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458213/how-to-work-with-base-8-octal-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458213/how-to-work-with-base-8-octal-numbers)

Comment: @Blindy 1. Ohhh that!! Well, that's something I forgot to edit, at first I learned that you can stop the loop by using integers, so I kinda played around with that, but then I want it to be a bit unique (by ending with char instead). Thank you for raising up the error, will edit it late
2. This is just a demo that I build just to test and figure out the problem that I mentioned, this Is in no way a complete build, so expect some error and nonsense, but again, thank for making a suggestion, will definitely change it in the final build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. In C/C++, [char](https://www.guru99.com/cpp-char.html) is a type that can be represented either by its character value (`'A'`, for example) or its numeric value (65). However, a digit's numeric value does not equal to itself.

```
'1' == 49
```

120 is the ASCII value of lower case x and since you loop with an int, it is logical that it will end up working in ways you do not expect it to work. You can change your

```
for (num = 0; num != stop; num++)
```

to

```
for (num = 0; ch != stop; num++)
```

and of course `ch` should be declared as `char` before your loop. Also, make sure that you replace `cin >> num;` with `cin >> ch;`

Comment: Ohhh I see!! I never knew that you could specify 2 different variables(num and char) in a for loop condition. I was always taught that once you put "num" in the condition, all the other conditions must include the "num" too. Thank you, you are a lifesaver!! I've literally been stuck on this problem for days

Comment: One more question tho!! now that we introduced the new variable, it came with a new slew of problems, now that we use ch (which is a char) when the users try to input the employee's ID (which is an int), the result as you expected, came out with an error. Now I can work around it by modifying the code to  
   cin >> ch >> num 
but I think it does not look good, and impractical. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @LeonAlvarez you can always convert a `char` into an `int` via `(int)ch`.

Comment: Sorry! but can you be more specific, where do put `(int)ch` at exactly? again I'm really sorry, I am mostly self-learning atm, since Covid is still a huge problem, Uni has not been great at all, so i am doing all this learning by myself sadly.

Comment: @LeonAlvarez Don't be sorry. You are having some difficulties we all had when we started. You can use the conversion above wherever you need the the numeric value of the `char` variable. If this is not helping you in getting through this problem, then you might want to edit your question with your current code, sepcifying which line you have a problem at. Then I will look into it. Unfortunately it is getting late here, so I will be available for a short while and then wrap up. If I do not write an answer to your current problem today, then I will see any comments that you may write tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243080/discussion-between-leon-alvarez-and-lajos-arpad).